# Resizing the sun room windows

Tags: windows, window-frame, sunroom

I have 6 windows in my sun room .size of the windows are approximately 6ft x 3ft. I want to rezize it to normal windows . all are old jalousie windows. Please let me know your ideas to make it more winter ready.please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: specify what is "normal size widow for you

Comment: Apparently you can use these strips slat vinyl which clips on the bottom slat and pressed against the top slat

Comment: Winter ready would be dual pane (glass)

Comment: Resizing windows usually requires quite a bit of re-building to make it look nice.  Winterizing windows can mean many different ideas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.